# Meteor accounts framework signed/logged in event

Tags: meteor

I'm using the `accounts-ui` package and would like to process some javascript as soon as the user is logged in/and or registered.

Is there an event that gets called as soon as the user signs in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the result of the `Meteor.userId()` function inside `Meteor.autorun():`

```
Meteor.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    console.log('The user logged in');
  }
});
```

Comment: There is an issue using autorun, during a page reload (or opening a url from the browsers end, if the user is already logged in it will still run autorun.

Comment: I see it now.  Very unfortunate.  I have tried a lot of different workarounds, to no avail :( You should file a feature request.

Answer (score 3):

The raw login API (eg `loginWithFacebook`, `loginWithPassword`, etc) has a callback that fires when login is complete, but this is not currently exposed through `accounts-ui`. This may change.

A potential workaround, inspired by Werner's suggestion, but also taking page load into account:

```
var oldUserId = undefined;

Meteor.autorun(function() {
  var newUserId = Meteor.userId();
  if (oldUserId === null && newUserId) {
    console.log('The user logged in');
  } else if (newUserId === null && oldUserId) {
    console.log('The user logged out');
  } 
  oldUserId = Meteor.userId();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an alternative; I monkey patched the callback function. It looks a bit more complex because the credentialRequestCompleteHandler requires a function that returns a function but besides that its a plain monkey patch. Stick this in main.js or something that gets processed late and only once. I hope it helps for future reference.

```
var orgCallback = Accounts.oauth.credentialRequestCompleteHandler;
Accounts.oauth.credentialRequestCompleteHandler = function(callback){
    return function (credentialTokenOrError) {
        var tmpFunc = orgCallback(callback);
        tmpFunc(credentialTokenOrError);
        alert("do your own thing here");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent way of doing it, in particular if you want an action to *only* run *once* on OAuth login. This callback does *not* fire if the user logs in via username / password.